# get unicode directory name in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, character-encoding, io

i am trying to get all directories from my usb drive using following code

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("H:\\");
DirectoryInfo[] allDir = di.GetDirectories();
```

this code works perfectly for directories with ascii names. but one directory has a name of 
" "(unicode value U+00A0). GetDirectories() cannot get that directory. is there a way to get directory wiht unicode name?

Comment: What happens? It just doesn't return it?

Comment: May be this can help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298136/file-paths-with-non-ascii-characters-and-fileinfo-in-c-sharp

Comment: Try `Directory.EnumerateDirectories()`.

Comment: only null is returned :(

Comment: Did you tried the [P/invoke Unicode](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/findfirstfile.html) version?

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo: internally `EnumerateDirectories` is the same call.

Comment: What filesystem is on your USB drive? The filesystem has to support Unicode. If it is FAT16 it won't.

Comment: CORRECTED: A file named only the Unicode Non-breaking space character is very odd indeed. Try passing `new DirectoryInfo("\\\\?\\H:\\");` instead... this bypasses a number of backwards-compatibility constraints.

Comment: Directory.EnumerateDirectories() worked for me. thanku @Farhad :)

Comment: OK I have tested this and on NTFS at least 1) normal `System.IO.Path` methods ***do create and  return** Unicode filenames just fine. 2) You cannot create a directory using `CreateDirectory` with the name `(char)160`, but you can rename an existing directory to have that name using the `DirectoryInfo.Move` command. 3) If you have a directory named with the single character `(char)160` then it ***is returned by `GetDirectories`***

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so what you're fighting is the .NET framework uses this signature of `FindFirstFile`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
internal static SafeFindHandle FindFirstFile(string fileName, [In, Out] Win32Native.WIN32_FIND_DATA data);
```

To then add insult to injury, you're fighting the language:

> Automatically marshal strings appropriately for the target operating system. The default is Unicode on Windows NT, Windows 2000, Windows XP, and the Windows Server 2003 family; the default is Ansi on Windows 98 and Windows Me. Although the common language runtime default is Auto, languages may override this default. **For example, by default C# marks all methods and types as Ansi.**

(from the `CharSet` enumeration documentation **emphasis added**)

The issue at hand is the `CharSet` parameter on the `DllImport`. This means that you're left with one approach; leverage the P/Invoke on your own. You'll need quite a few things. First you'll need the data structure that is returned:

```
[BestFitMapping(false)]
[Serializable]
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
internal class WIN32_FIND_DATA
{
  internal int dwFileAttributes;
  internal uint ftCreationTime_dwLowDateTime;
  internal uint ftCreationTime_dwHighDateTime;
  internal uint ftLastAccessTime_dwLowDateTime;
  internal uint ftLastAccessTime_dwHighDateTime;
  internal uint ftLastWriteTime_dwLowDateTime;
  internal uint ftLastWriteTime_dwHighDateTime;
  internal int nFileSizeHigh;
  internal int nFileSizeLow;
  internal int dwReserved0;
  internal int dwReserved1;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
  internal string cFileName;
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 14)]
  internal string cAlternateFileName;

  [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
  public WIN32_FIND_DATA()
  {
  }
}
```

Next you'll need the right import for `FindFirstFile`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
internal static SafeFindHandle FindFirstFile(string fileName, [In, Out] Win32Native.WIN32_FIND_DATA data);
```

Next you'll need `GetLastWin32Error` to check for errors; that can be accessed via [`Marshal.GetLastWin32Error`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getlastwin32error%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in the `InteropServices` namespace.

Next you're going to need to iterate, so you'll need `FindNextFile`:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true, BestFitMapping = false)]
internal static bool FindNextFile(SafeFindHandle hndFindFile, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct), In, Out] Win32Native.WIN32_FIND_DATA lpFindFileData);
```

Armed with these you can build your own iterator. However, for your benefit here is what Microsoft does for "init":

```
[SecurityCritical]
private void CommonInit()
{
  string fileName = Path.InternalCombine(this.searchData.fullPath, this.searchCriteria);
  Win32Native.WIN32_FIND_DATA wiN32FindData = new Win32Native.WIN32_FIND_DATA();
  this._hnd = Win32Native.FindFirstFile(fileName, wiN32FindData);
  if (this._hnd.IsInvalid)
  {
    int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    switch (lastWin32Error)
    {
      case 2:
      case 18:
        this.empty = this.searchData.searchOption == SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly;
        break;
      default:
        this.HandleError(lastWin32Error, this.searchData.fullPath);
        break;
    }
  }
  if (this.searchData.searchOption == SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
  {
    if (this.empty)
    {
      this._hnd.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
      SearchResult searchResult = this.CreateSearchResult(this.searchData, wiN32FindData);
      if (!this._resultHandler.IsResultIncluded(searchResult))
        return;
      this.current = this._resultHandler.CreateObject(searchResult);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    this._hnd.Dispose();
    this.searchStack.Add(this.searchData);
  }
}
```

and here is what they do for "iterate" for what you're looking for:

```
  if (this.searchData != null && this._hnd != null)
  {
    while (Win32Native.FindNextFile(this._hnd, wiN32FindData))
    {
      SearchResult searchResult = this.CreateSearchResult(this.searchData, wiN32FindData);
      if (this._resultHandler.IsResultIncluded(searchResult))
      {
        if (this.needsParentPathDiscoveryDemand)
        {
          this.DoDemand(this.searchData.fullPath);
          this.needsParentPathDiscoveryDemand = false;
        }
        this.current = this._resultHandler.CreateObject(searchResult);
        return true;
      }
    }
    int lastWin32Error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    if (this._hnd != null)
      this._hnd.Dispose();
    if (lastWin32Error != 0 && lastWin32Error != 18 && lastWin32Error != 2)
      this.HandleError(lastWin32Error, this.searchData.fullPath);
  }
```

**NOTE:** you're not going to be able to use this code directly, you'll have to fit it to your solution, but this is a huge jump start on the API's. Get you a copy of [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) to fill in the gaps.

**NOTE:** the `fileName` parameter accepted by `FindFirstFile` is going to the parent directory. In your case, `H:\`.

Comment: OK I have tested this and on NTFS at least 1) normal `System.IO.Path` methods ***do create and  return** Unicode filenames just fine. 2) You cannot create a directory using `CreateDirectory` with the name `(char)160`, but you can rename an existing directory to have that name using the `DirectoryInfo.Move` command. 3) If you have a directory named with the single character `(char)160` then it ***is returned by `GetDirectories`***